# How to tunnel pcf service from spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a spring boot application deployed on **pivotal cloud foundry**.
I'm trying to tunnel **(cf ssh)** to that application in pcf from my spring boot application, but not able to find any api or client libraries to achieve it.

**Actual cli command to tunnel pcf:**
cf ssh -N -T -L 10001:localhost:10001 ms name

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to write Java code that would do the same thing as the `cf ssh` command, that should be possible. It's standard SSH, but with short-lived credentials so the trick will be generating credentials that you can use from your app.

Here's an example of using a standard SSH/SCP/SFTP client, note that `ssh.bosh-lite.com` will be your SSH domain, which you can see from `cf curl /v2/info`:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 cf:$(cf app app-name --guid)/0@ssh.bosh-lite.com
$ scp -P 2222 -oUser=cf:$(cf app app-name --guid)/0 my-local-file.json ssh.bosh-lite.com:my-remote-file.json
$ sftp -P 2222 cf:$(cf app app-name --guid)/0@ssh.bosh-lite.com
```

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh#cloud-foundry-via-cloud-controller-and-uaa

---

That said, you should be able to do something similar with any standard SSH Java library.

As mentioned above, the trick is in getting credentials. The username will be the format `cf:application-guid/app-instance-number`, which is easy, but the password needs to be generated with `cf ssh-code`, or the comparable call to the UAA API.

Ex: `curl -vv -H 'Accept: application/json' -H "Authorization: $(cf oauth-token)" "https://uaa.run.pivotal.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=ssh-proxy&response_type=code"`

This example uses `curl` to send the request and `cf oauth-token` to get a valid Oauth2 bearer token for the logged in user. You could get a valid bearer token in a number of ways, including making direct API calls or using the cf-java-client. It just needs to be a valid token for the user that should perform the SSH action (i.e. it would be the user that's running `cf ssh`).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. 



Yes we are trying to write Java code that would do the same thing as the `cf ssh` command. Could you please confirm whether any api or client library is available in pcf to use ssh tunneling. We could not find any api in cloud foundry docs. PFB the url.



http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/9.5.0/

Comment: There is no API call to do this. You do need to use the API to get access code, but as far as making the SSH connection, that is just a normal SSH connection.